# How should I use my returned value or use a function in another function?

Tags: python

Hi I just made a program and i'm trying to return my "choix_menu" value but the problem is that when i'm in the function it show the right value (if i write 1 it will show 1) but outside it (I used a return) it dont want to give me the right value and give me 0 as it is the default value I defined for "choix_menu" before the function.

```
def menu():
    print ("Welcome to a toolbox\n")
    print ("Current Options  :\n1. IP Finder\n\n")

    choix_menu = input("Select a number : ")
    choix_menu= int(choix_menu)

    print("Inside:  ", choix_menu)

    if choix_menu!=1:
        print("\nError, selected value can't  be accepted.")
        sleep(10)

    return choix_menu

menu()
print("Outside: ", choix_menu)
```

PS: I made this because I didn't find how to use a function in another function (like if I want to use a "first()" function in my second function; so if anyone know anything about that (is it even possible?) I would like to know more about it

Comment: `choix_menu = menu()`

Answer (score 0):

When you return a value from a function, you need to capture it in a variable otherwise it will not work properly. So in your case, just add `choice = menu()` and then print it using `print("Outside: ", choice)` and it'll work.